# Using iloc for indexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, uilocalnotification

Here is my dataset:

[image]

I want to put in the column 'Solicitud de personacion' if its values are zero the values in the column 'Solicitud de personacion_'. I use a loop and the iloc function to index, but it doesn't work. What are the solutions?

```
hito = 'Solicitud personacion'
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[hito].iloc[i] != 0:
        a[hito].iloc[i] = a[hito].iloc[i]
    else:
        a[hito].iloc[i] = a[hito + '_'].iloc[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where`:

```
df['Solicitud personacion'] = df['Solicitud de personacion_'].where(df['Solicitud personacion'].eq(0), df['Solicitud personacion'])
```

Comment: This sets the non-zero values of "Solicitud personacion" to 0, where they are expected to remain the same (according to the code they tried with). The second argument in `where` should be `df['Solicitud personacion']` instead of 0

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mixed up the condition (thought was already 0)